# How to open specific profile at chrome - Automation C#

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I have Chrome browser with profile manager
how i can open the browser direct instance with a specific profile ?
i'm learning C# Automation!

10x

i try to open the browser direct instance with a specific profile ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add user Data Directory argument to chrome options and provide path to your profile

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

// Specify the path to the Chrome profile
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=pathtoProfile\\Profile 3");

// Create a new instance of ChromeDriver with the options
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```